# android studio responsive table

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablelayout

I have a table in my android studio app. The problem is that is isn't responsive. How can I turn it to responsive layout?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:stretchColumns="1"
    android:background="@drawable/white">

    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:text="Table"
            android:padding="3dip"/>
        <TextView
            android:text="SERIA NR. 11691428"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:padding="3dip"/>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: By responsive, Do you mean mobile responsive?

Comment: when screen is rotated some data lost

Comment: Also see this link. Good for your information perhaps.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/difference-between-px-dp-dip-and-sp-in-android

Answer (score 0):

Try to read from this link.
It contains material regarding the UI Design.

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/07/26/android-design-tips/

One more thing,
If Android Native is not your strict requirement.
You can use "Sencha Framework" . It is great with great backend and UI features.

Answer (score 0):

you must create different layout, based on the dimension of the various screens.
So in your /res folder, you will have /layout/main.xml (default size) but also /layout-small/main.xml
/layout-large/main.xml

et cetera. Obviously, in every main.xml you must set the right dimensions and margins.